# How to reset the form validations of angularjs after closing the bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

> Here I applied angularjs form validations for a form which is in a bootstrap model.But what the issue is ,the error messages and the dat in text fields remain same even after closing the model`

```
<div class="modal fade loginpopup index" id="login-modal"   tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
         <div class="modal-dialog login-form animated">
             <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                      <form  name="loginform">
                          <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="login" name="login">
                                    <div class="form-group" >
                                         <input type="email" id="userName" name="userName" class="form-control" ng-model="email" placeholder="UserName" required >
                                         <span class="has-error" ng-show="loginform.userName.$touched && loginform.userName.$invalid" class="font-ten">
                                                <span class="has-error"   ng-show="loginform.userName.$error.email" class="font-ten">Invalid  email address.</span>
                                                <span class="has-error" ng-show="loginform.userName.$error.required" class="font-ten">UserName is required..</span>


                                            </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" id="psd" name="psd" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"   required >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group text-center" >
                                            <button class="btn btn3d text-center imm" type="submit" > Log In     </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group login-index" style="margin-bottom:0px;padding-top:0px !important">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="Option">
                                            <label class="Option" for="Option"> Rememer Me </label>
                                            <a href="/#forgetpassword" data-toggle="tab"  id="forgotpsw">Forgot Password?</a>
                                        </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tab-pane" id="forgetpassword">
                                    <div class="form-group " >
                                        <input type="email" id = "emailId" name="emailId" required class="form-control"  placeholder="Email Address" >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-actions text-center">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn3d imm"  >Submit </button>
                                    </div>


                             </div>
                           </div>
                      </form>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Empty your model and set the form to pristine state using setPristine() method.

Comment: can u please elaboraet the code

Comment: Why are you not using ng-model to store the input values ?

Comment: sorry i am using ng-model but i forget to post it please check it once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On closing your bootstrap modal, do this :

```
loginform.setPristine();
```

This will set the form to pristine state i.e it will clear all the validations applied to the form and make it as it was untouched. But you have to clear the input values separately before doing this.

Comment: it is not working

Comment: It should work. How are you getting the "loginForm" in your controller ?

Comment: $scope.reset = function() {
      
    loginform.setPristine();
    }

i have written like dis in a controller

Comment: It'll not work like that. Did you define "loginForm" in your controller ? If not, pass the loginForm in the reset() function when you call it on closing the modal. Please try to create a jsfiddle and share that link.

Comment: yes ,I didnt define the loginform in my controller,, here,loginform is form name,right?,, can u make me know how to define it in a controller

Comment: Post your controller code  or it's better create a fiddle with your code and I'll change it there.